# Oracle SSL authentication wallet no longer working

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I'm running test to connect to locally installed Oracle DB using SSL Oracle wallet.

I was able to create the wallet and use them for authentication successfully around two weeks ago. But this no longer seems to be working. Here is how I created the wallets.

**Create Server wallet and export certificate:**

```
orapki wallet create -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Server" -pwd Welcome1 -auto_login

orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Server" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=MyHostName.Domain.com" -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 3650 -sign_alg sha256

orapki wallet export -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Server" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=MyHostName.Domain.com" -cert C:/app/TestWallet/MyHostName-certificate.crt
```

**Create Client wallet and export certificate:**

```
orapki wallet create -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Client" -pwd Welcome1 -auto_login

orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Client" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=DBUserName" -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 3650 -sign_alg sha256

orapki wallet export -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Client" -pwd Welcome1 -dn "CN=DBUserName" -cert C:/app/TestWallet/DBUserName-certificate.crt
```

**Exchange Certificate:**

```
orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Client" -pwd Welcome1 -trusted_cert -cert C:/app/TestWallet/MyHostName-certificate.crt

orapki wallet add -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Server" -pwd Welcome1 -trusted_cert -cert C:/app/TestWallet/DBUserName-certificate.crt
```

**Wallet display (Server):**

```
orapki wallet display -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Server" -pwd Welcome1

Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Subject:        CN=MyHostName.Domain.com
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=DBUserName
Subject:        CN=MyHostName.Domain.com
```

**Wallet display (Client):**

```
orapki wallet display -wallet "C:/app/TestWallet/Client" -pwd Welcome1

Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Subject:        CN=DBUserName
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=DBUserName
Subject:        CN=MyHostName.Domain.com
```

**Server sqlnet.ora**

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\app\TestWallet\Server)
    )
  )
```

**Client sqlnet.ora**

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\app\TestWallet\Client)
    )
  )
```

I'm testing using OCCI Instant Client.

```
Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
Connection *conn = env->createConnection(m_username.c_str(), m_password.c_str(), m_dbConnectionString.c_str());
// Note: username and password is not supplied to above function.
```

Above code throw exception as below:

```
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
```

I was able to create wallet and connect normally 2 weeks ago but this no longer seems to be working.
If I set wallet path in `sqlnet.ora` to use old one from 2 weeks ago, I'm able to connect fine.

I'm sure that wallet path is correct. LSNRCTL also confirmed that the wallet path is right:

```
LSNRCTL> status

 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=MyHostName.Domain.com)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\app\TestWallet\Server))
```

What might have I missed? How to make wallet SSL authentication to work?

**EDIT:**
If in `sqlnet.ora` file, I change the wallet to path to use old wallet that I created 2 weeks ago. It is still working. The problem occur for only newly created wallet.

Comment: Since changing the server wallet, have you restarted the server?

Comment: @pmdba Yes. I have restarted the Oracle Service. Even rebooting doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I just missed one more settings in the Server's `listener.ora`
This time I was creating wallet in different location than previous test.

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\app\TestWallet\Server)
    )
  )
```

Changing this follow by:

```
LSNRCTL> stop
LSNRCTL> start
```

Wait some time for it to update. Now got it up and running.